# Random subgraph properties

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, graph-theory, random-graphs, complex-networks

Consider a graph $G$ of $N$ vertices and $M$ edges, and assume $G$ has typical [complex network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_network) properties: it is not necessarily [connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)), but it has a *high* [clustering coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient) and a [giant connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_component) with *low* average [distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory)).

Now, consider a graph $G'$ defined as the sub-graph of $G$ induced by a randomly chosen set of $n$ vertices. Let us denote by $m$ its number of edges.

- Is $G'$ likely to have the typical properties of an [Erdős–Rényi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model) random graph?
- What is the expected value of $m$?

Thank you.

Comment: If the graph is complete then any random subgraph is complete. If the graph is a cycle (path) and $n$ is small enough then the subgraph will be empty with positive probability.

Comment: I didn't mention, but the graph G is in fact a real-world graph (citation graph), which is not connected, so it is not complete.

Comment: And I think graph G has some properties of a small-world graph: small average path length and high clustering coefficient

Comment: My intention was to show that, as formulated, the question does not make sense.

Comment: You need to formulate your question precisely to attract interest.

Comment: I re-formulated my question (two questions actually). Is it understandable now? @kodlu

Comment: It is now less understandable. There is no such thing as real world graph. The other properties hold in a complete graph.

Comment: @dodd I think there are many examples for a real-world graph, like a social network, a citation graph, or a protein graph.

Comment: It would be interesting to know examples of non-real world graphs.

Comment: @dodd I do understand your concern with the concept of _real-world graph_ ;) I tried to give a better formulation.

Answer (score 2):

I fear the question is difficult in its general form: the answer will strongly depends on the assumptions we make regarding the initial graph, and on how we choose $n$.

As noticed by @dodd, in particular, the sampling applied to a complete graph will lead to a complete sub-graph. Likewise, an initially empty graph will lead to an empty sub-graph.

But I guess we should assume a **sparse graph with high clustering coefficient**. The low average distance is not a very significant property.

If $n$ is large, close to $N$, then we only remove some nodes, and so we may expect a sub-graph with large clustering coefficient too.

If $n$ is low, far from $N$, then the nodes we choose have a high probability of *not* being linked together, since the graph is sparse, and we may end with an almost empty graph. It may then be similar to an ER graph with only few edges.

To go further, I think we have to study the *probability to sample several neighbours of a same node*, since they have a high probability to be linked together (clustering coefficient). To evaluate this, I suggest we look at the degree distribution of the initial graph, and at its degree-clustering correlations.

I think it's all I can say without additional information.