# Random graphs defined by a set of tiles

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs

Related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4057871/graph-puzzles-constructing-graphs-from-tiles), which I asked at MSE, I'd like to ask this one here:

Consider a (large) graph $G$ and its multi-set of tiles $T$, i.e. the multi-set of its vertex-induced subgraphs, i.e. the multi-set of pointed graphs (one for each vertex) containing the vertex and all of its neighbours, together with all the edges between them.

Define the set $\Gamma(T)$ of all  graphs having the same tile set $T$.

How would you calculate some expected properties $P$ of these graphs in the sense of "almost all graphs in $\Gamma(T)$ have property $P$". If "almost all" was to mean "in the limit $|V(G)| \rightarrow \infty$" one would interpret a given tile set $T$ as defining *ratios* of tiles, i.e. counting relative instead of absolute numbers per single (isomorphism class of) tile.

There are two "properties" literally *all* graphs in $\Gamma(T)$ do have: the (same) degree distribution and the (same) distribution of [clustering coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient). By which means do I find and calculate other properties that almost all graphs in $\Gamma(T)$ have?

Comment: You may be interested in the fact that your tiles are called ego-networks in social sciences, and sometimes considered as building blocks of global social networks; from this perspective, the elements of $\Gamma(T)$ are possible social networks for a given set of ego-networks. See _e.g._ "Graphlet-based characterization of many ego networks" by Charbey and Prieur: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01764253v2

Comment: @MatthieuLatapy: This was exactly the background of my question, even though I've never heard the terms "ego-network" and "graphlet" before. Thanks a lot for the link! A nice coincidence.

Comment: Quite different but related problem: the graph reconstruction conjecture claims that graphs of $n$ vertices are determined by their induced sub-graphs of $n-1$ vertices, called _cards_ in this context: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstruction_conjecture

Comment: @MatthieuLatapy: Thanks for the hint! I mentioned that in [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4057871/graph-puzzles-constructing-graphs-from-tiles) that I linked to.

Comment: Sorry I missed it. But let me mention yet another quite different but somewhat related approach: Lovasz, in his book _Large Networks and Graph Limits_, proposes to analyze graphs through the frequency of subgraphs induced by random sets of $k$ vertices, up to isomorphism. Then, the _tiles_ are the subgraphs induced by $k$ random vertices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question you ask is, in my opinion, extremely important: **decomposing** a graph into a (small) set of small graphs (the *tiles* or *ego-centered* sub-graphs, for instance), and then characterizing how these small graphs are **combined** in the initial graph and how this induces its properties,
certainly is a great way to get insight on the graph under concern. This is a typical [reductionnist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductionism) approach.

Let me explain a small step we made in this direction a few years ago.
First notice that many graphs met in practice have a high local density, captured, e.g., by the [clustering coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient) (which is nothing but the density of your tiles). We said that this may be seen as an indication of the fact that these graphs are composed of many [cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) combined together. In other words, they are [projection of bipartite graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_network_projection) (either a known bipartite graph, or built from an [edge clique cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover) of the graph, or another set of cliques such that each edge belongs to at least one). The structure of this bipartite graph tells what clique sizes arisen and how they are combined to get the whole graph.

[image: A bipartite graph and its projection]

We explored in particular two kinds of bipartite graphs: random ones with prescribed degree distributions, and some produced by a kind of [preferential attachment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferential_attachment). More details are available in the paper
[*Bipartite Graphs as Models of Complex Networks*](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0307095), by
Jean-Loup Guillaume and myself, and formal analysis is available in [*A scale-free graph model based on bipartite graphs*](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00730793) by Etienne Birmelé. It is shown in particular that **the degree distribution and clustering coefficient of graphs under concern may be seen as consequence of such an underlying bipartite structure.**

One may iterate this idea and describe the obtained bipartite graph by a tripartite graph encoding its bipartite cliques, see [*A random model that relies on maximal bicliques to preserve the overlaps in bipartite networks*](https://www.complexnetworks.fr/a-random-model-that-relies-on-maximal-bicliques-to-preserve-the-overlaps-in-bipartite-networks-5/) by Fabien Tarissan and Lionel Tabourier. More theoretical work on the iteration of such operators is available in [*On the Termination of Some Biclique Operators on Multipartite Graphs*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.04451) by Christophe Crespelle, myself, and Thi Ha Duong Phan, as well as in [*Termination of Multipartite Graph Series Arising from Complex Network Modelling*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.04447) by myself, Thi Ha Duong Phan, Christophe Crespelle, and Thanh Qui Nguyen.

This is quite far from what you primarily ask, though, as this is focused only on clique tiles that are not necessarily defined as in your post. Still, I hope this gives some insight.

Answer (score 1):

To whom it may be of interest: Find [here](http://syspedia.de/EgoNetworks/Ego-centric%20graphs.pdf) a short paper where I describe a graph generation model that takes a set of ego-networks and ties them together in a systematic (and possibly realistic) way. The ego-networks are not fully specified, only their size (number of nodes $n$) and their density (number of edges $m$) are given. Beyond that, they are assumed to be [Erdős–Rényi graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model) from $G(n,m)$. The graph as a whole is composed of many such small Erdős–Rényi graphs, while other (more structured) characterizations of the ego-networks are conceivable. The paper is basically an elaboration of Matthieu Latapy's first comment on the question.

The model bears some similarity with [configuration models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_model).

Comment: @MatthieuLatapy: Thanks again for your comments and answer!

Comment: My pleasure. You may be interested in this question too, where I discuss a model in which each vertex belongs to a prescribed number of triangles and (non-triangle edges) : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383913/random-graphs-with-prescibed-degrees-and-triangles This is not so far from a model where each vertex would belong to a prescribed number of each type of ego-networks, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in research by Nicolas Trotignon, among others, which is somewhat complementary: characterising families of graphs by a subset of patterns (graphs) that *do not* appear in them.
E. g. [triangle-free graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle-free_graph).

Nice idea btw, your generation model based on tiles / ego networks.